# understanding second l'Hopital rule theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I'm reading the second L'Hopital rule theorem and I'm having hard time understanding the beginning of the proof.

Let the functions $f$ and $g$ are defined, they have continuous derivatives in the open interval $(a,b)$ and $g'(x) \ne 0$ everywhere in the interval 
$(a,b)$.

Let 
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=+\infty
$$
and let $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}$ exists in a generalised sense. Then
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(a)}{g(a)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}.
$$

Proof:

We see that $g'(x) < 0$ and therefore $g(x)$ is monotonically decreasing. It is clear that $g(x)>0$ for values close enough to a. Lets look at the case when the limit of $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists and it is equal to a real number l.

Lets fix $\epsilon>0$. Then in the interval $(a,b)$ there exists a point $x_0$ s.t. for every $x$ between $a$ and $x_0$ we have
$$
|\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}.
$$
Let x be an arbitrary point between $a$ and $x_0$. We apply Cauchy's mean value theorem for the interval $[x, x_0]$.
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-g(x_0)}=\frac{f'(\zeta)}{g'(\zeta)}, \zeta \in (a,x_0)
$$
From where
$$
|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-g(x_0)}-l|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}.
$$

Lets denote 
$$
A(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-g(x_0)}, B(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)}, C(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.
$$

We see that
$B(x)-A(x) \to 0$ and $C(x)-B(x)\to 0$ as $x \to a$.

Lets chose $\delta > 0$ such that, $a+\delta<x_0$ and for every $x\in (a, a+\delta)$ we have

$|B(x)-A(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and $|C(x)-B(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$

Then for $x\in(a,a+\delta)$ we have
$$|C(x)-l|\le |C(x)-B(x)|+|B(x)-A(x)|+|A(x)-l|<\epsilon$$.

**My question:**

Why $|C(x)-l|\le |C(x)-B(x)|+|B(x)-A(x)|+|A(x)-l|$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a frequently-used trick.

$|x-y| = |x-z+z-w+w-y|<|x-z|+|z-w|+|w-y|$

So it is just the triangle inequality.